Optimize VHS Capturing with OBS Studio
My setup is: VHS > AV2HDMI > UGreen HDMI capture device.

Is the bit rate overkill?
How about incoming resolution and scaled output, should I go smaller?
It seems to currently output 15MB/min, which seems high?

Generally speaking, existing video files seem to play ok. Just wondering if there could be something else I could be looking at. So far, seems ok, but I'm not sure.
My OBS settings:


